# JQueryUI Drag and Drop accept with nested lists

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable, nested-lists

In this nested list example: http://jsfiddle.net/7e2gs/, the accept function on the droppable items is returning the expected value (false, when the droppable is a child item of the draggable).

However, the activeClass is being applied to all the droppables, not just the ones that had the accept function return true.

How do I get the activeClass to be applied only to the items that had the accept function return true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the "IsNotInsideSelf" function.

The returned variable of the function had the same name as the function and was causing the the accept function to behave as if it was not working.